# Who killed this character in "The Commuter"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-commuter

In [*The Commuter* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1590193/), a mysterious woman - Joanna - tasks a regular commuter - Michael - to find a train passenger "who doesn't belong here". Later we find, that she has her own man on board tasked with "taking care of" the person that Michael has to find.

During the course of the movie,

> Michael finds who was Joanna's man - the black "musician" with a guitar - and he kills him.

Joanna then calls Michael and tells him to take the gun and use it - when he refuses, she says "so everybody dies". We find soon after that

> the train engine driver is dead and the train won't stop.

**But how could he be killed if Michael has taken care of Joanna's man?** Was there someone else on board working for her? If so, why that person didn't attack Michael?

Up to the next-to-last stop, the train works as expected (not counting the faulty air conditioning), so my guess is that the engineer was alive for most of the journey.

Comment: The consideration could also be made that the engineer was meant to be dead. That either way, everyone was intended to die, but that Joanna wanted to test Michael before it all ended.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan possibly, but the engineer was most likely alive for the most of the journey - the train was stopping as expected, only after Michael kills her agent the train starts to behave badly.

Comment: That’s a good point. Another thought I had when I watched the film: the engineer was in on it and was on a suicide mission to kill himself when instructed to, or the engine was booby trapped somehow. I’m more partial to the latter. Explosive device under the driver’s seat or sniper correctly positioned to hit the engineer if Michael didn’t make the right decision or make ip his mind in time.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I really, really doubt about the suicide mission, sniper show is also doubtful since Joanna couldn't predict when Michael would change his mind so sniper would have to follow the train and shot a moving target or shoot from the inside - hence again it would mean that there was someone else planted on the train